# Add a row to my table using Javascript and MVC

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table like this on my MVC view

```
 <table class="PBHEP table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center">Compute PBHEP Offsets</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center">Present Conditions</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table class="PDHEPparams table table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Township</th>
            <th>Range</th>
            <th>Section</th>
            <th>Crop</th>
            <th>Acres</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="rowtoadd">
            <td style =" text-align:center">
                <input  type="button" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" value="+" onclick="addrow"></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center">
                <input class="input-small" type="text" placeholder="Township"></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center">
                <input class="input-small" type="text" placeholder="Range"></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center">
                <input class="input-small" type="text" placeholder="Section"></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center">
                <select></select></td>
            <td style =" text-align:center">
                <input class="input-small" type="text" placeholder="Acres"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

How do I add a new row to this table on the button click ? what should be my javascript function for the button onclick.

Comment: What MVC framework are you using? You didn't specify.

Comment: I think if you understood mvc correcly, you already know that you need some Javascript code to actually **work in an MVC fashion**, if you know how to write this code, I'm quite sure you can answer your question by yourself. Otherwise, you need at least provide us your MVC code to handle dom in this way, or tell us which is your framework. If that's not the case, you can just remove any "mvc" tag and reference from your question and get a plain javascript help.

Comment: MVC is a language agnostic design pattern. It has nothing to do with how javascript manipulates your badly written HTML table.

Comment: I am using MVC 4 with razor view

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general idea of it.

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {
  var township = $('.input-small').eq(0).val();
  var range = $('.input-small').eq(1).val();
  var section = $('.input-small').eq(2).val();
  var acres = $('.input-small').eq(3).val();
  $('.PDHEPparams tbody').append("<tr><td>" + township + "</td><td>" + range + "</td><td>" + section + "</td><td>" + acres + "</td></tr>");
});
```

Here is a rough [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q3w9m/).

Comment: this fiddle does not add the new row.do i need to mention the element ID some where??

Comment: It works for me.  Its not styled but it does add a row.  What is not working for you?

Comment: Its not adding the row when I click the + button

Comment: Hmm I don't know what to tell you.  It is working for me.  The table is not styled and it just shows up as plain text but it is adding the row.